# woocommerce_before_calculate_totals hook stopped working after update to WC 3.0.1

Tags: woocommerce

I have updated to WC 3.0.1 from 2.6.14.
My original code is as follows:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    $custom_price = 10; // This will be your custome price  
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
    }
}
```

It is no longer updating the price in cart or minicart.

Comment: You can no longer directly access `$product` properties. You should see a warning about this in the `debug.log` if you enabled `WP_DEBUG`. You must use setters and getters now for product, order, order item, and coupon objects.

Comment: Thanks helgatheviking,

Could you please provide an example for getting and setting price of product ?

Comment: Look at `set_price()` in the [source](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.0.0/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L804-L806)

Comment: Please write out a complete answer for future visitors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic cart item pricing not working on orders in WooCommerce 3.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885585/dynamic-cart-item-pricing-not-working-on-orders-in-woocommerce-3-0)

Answer (score 8):

For overriding product price on cart in the latest version of Woocommerce (3.0.1) try using set_price( $price ) function in woocommerce this will help. [Source here](http://www.pjvillanueva.com/overriding-product-price-in-woocommerce-version-3-0-1/)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'woocommerce_pj_update_price', 99 );

function woocommerce_pj_update_price() {

    $custom_price = $_COOKIE["donation"]; // This will be your custom price  
    $target_product_id = 413; //Product ID

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        if($cart_item['data']->get_id() == $target_product_id){

            $cart_item['data']->set_price($custom_price);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: 3 hours of my time wasted looking for a solution to this. Thanks to you is not 3 days...

Answer (score 0):

Works with a little change:

```
//OLD:
$value['data']->price = $custom_price;

//NEW:
$value['data']->set_price( $custom_price );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    $custom_price = 10; // This will be your custome price  
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        $value['data']->set_price( $custom_price );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price', 10, 1);
function add_custom_price( $cart_obj ) {

    //  This is necessary for WC 3.0+
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    foreach ( $cart_obj->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {
        $value['data']->set_price( 40 );
    }
 }
```

if i set $value['data']->set_price( 40 ) work fine, but:

```
 foreach ( $cart_obj->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {
            $price = 50;
            $value['data']->set_price( $price );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is you are calling price directly at `$value['data']->price`.
Make it:

```
$value['data']->get_price()
```

and I think you problem will be fixed