# Change cart item prices in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I am trying to change product price in cart using the following function:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shipping_calculator', 'add_custom_price' 
     );
      function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
         foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
         $value['data']->price = 400;
        } 
     }
```

It was working correctly in WooCommerce version 2.6.x but not working anymore in version 3.0+

How can I make it work in WooCommerce Version 3.0+?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [woocommerce\_before\_calculate\_totals hook stopped working after update to WC 3.0.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43285252/woocommerce-before-calculate-totals-hook-stopped-working-after-update-to-wc-3-0)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**Update 2021** *(Handling mini cart custom item price)*

With **WooCommerce version 3.0+** you need:

- To use **`woocommerce_before_calculate_totals`** hook instead.
- To use [WC_Cart **`get_cart()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_get_cart) method instead
- To use [WC_product **`set_price()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_set_price) method instead

Here is the code:

```
// Set custom cart item price
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price', 1000, 1);
function add_custom_price( $cart ) {
    // This is necessary for WC 3.0+
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Avoiding hook repetition (when using price calculations for example | optional)
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $cart_item['data']->set_price( 40 );
    }
}
```

And for mini cart *(update)*:

```
// Mini cart: Display custom price 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'filter_cart_item_price', 10, 3 );
function filter_cart_item_price( $price_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

    if( isset( $cart_item['custom_price'] ) ) {
        $args = array( 'price' => 40 );

        if ( WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) {
            $product_price = wc_get_price_including_tax( $cart_item['data'], $args );
        } else {
            $product_price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $cart_item['data'], $args );
        }
        return wc_price( $product_price );
    }
    return $price_html;
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

This code is tested and works *(still works on WooCommerce 5.1.x)*.

> **Note:** you can **increase the hook priority** from **`20`** to **`1000`** *(or even ***`2000`***)* when using some few specific plugins or others customizations.

Related:

- [Set cart item price from a hidden input field custom price in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52303818/set-cart-item-price-from-a-hidden-input-field-custom-price-in-woocommerce-3/52304377#52304377)
- [Change cart item prices based on custom cart item data in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47646781/change-cart-item-price-based-on-custom-cart-data-in-woocommerce)
- [Set a specific product price conditionally on Woocommerce single product page & cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50574699/set-a-specific-product-price-conditionally-on-woocommerce-single-product-page/50575469#50575469)
- [Add a select field that will change price in Woocommerce simple products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49862061/add-a-select-field-that-will-change-price-in-woocommerce-simple-products/49866912#49866912)

Comment: Hi, #LoicTheAztec this solution is working correctly for hard coded values but not working for dynamic values.

Comment: How can we make these values dynamic?

Comment: @AsifRao What do you need exactly, could you be more spécific please?

Comment: I want to add custom price for the product added in cart using add_to_cart();
so need the product_id and custom price that I have calculated. in this whook. how can I get these values in this hook.

Comment: @AsifRao So sorry but this answer is not related to add_to_cart() functionality… you should need to ask a new question on StackOverFlow…

Answer (score 1):

With WooCommerce version 3.2.6, @LoicTheAztec's answer works for me if I increase the priority to 1000.

`add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price', 1000, 1);`

I tried priority values of `10`,`99` and `999` but the price and total in my cart did not change (even though I was able to confirm with `get_price()` that `set_price()` had actually set the price of the item.

I have a custom hook that adds a fee to my cart and I'm using a 3rd party plugin that adds product attributes.  I suspect that these WooCommerce "add-ons" introduce delays that require me to delay my custom action.

Comment: I'm using WC-Fields-Factory plugin version 2.0.6 to add custom product attributes.  I grepped the plugin directory for 999 and found multiple instances in the plugin where the action priority is 999.  I'm guessing that, in my case, this is why I needed a priority of 1000.