# Updating WooCommerce product price dynamically whilst adding custom information to order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I currently have a function that runs when a user selects an option on part of the site, this retrieves a price. I need to basically run a function that adds the specific product to the basket, alters its price to that price and also adds some custom meta that also gets passed from the first function.

```
sendPrices(5000, 'Nice Title', 'Wednesday', 809);

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function sendPrices($price, $orderTitle, $orderDispatch, $productID) {
   global $woocommerce; 
   $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($productID);
   add_custom_price($price, $orderTitle, $orderDispatch, $productID)
}

function add_custom_price( $cart_object, $price, $orderTitle, $orderDispatch ) {
    $custom_price = $price; // This will be your custome price  
    $target_product_id = $productID;
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $value ) {
        if ( $value['product_id'] == $productID ) {
            $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see from the above code, Its repeating information and I'm struggling to get it working as imagined, I don't know how to incorporate the meta information $orderTitle, and $orderDispatch. I need these to pull through to the checkout and complete order invoice.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: WooCommerce 3.0 no longer allows direct access to object properties (ex: `$product->price`. You must use `$product->set_price($price)`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43327167/383847)