# Add a select field that will change price in Woocommerce simple products

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, html-select

I need to add a select with a custom price in the single product as seen in the screenshots below;

[image: HTML select dropdown]

[image]

The idea is that by selecting an option from (select) you can increase it to the base price.

Without using the variations, since my idea is to do other things more, but I need help on how to do this.

I've seen plugins that do it are called "Add-On" but I do not want to use a plugin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add a select field in simple products (like in variable products) that will update base price depending on the dopdown selected value, try this:

```
// Frontend: custom select field in product single pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'fabric_length_product_field' );
function fabric_length_product_field() {
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type('variable') ) return; // Not variable products

    $domain = 'woocommerce';
    $text   = array(
        __('cards', $domain),
        __('card', $domain),
        __('Total', $domain),
        get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(),
    );

    // Select Options array
    $options = array(
        ""          => __('Select package'),
        "12.00" => "1000 {$text[0]} - {$text[3]}0.012/{$text[1]} - {$text[2]} {$text[3]}12.00",
        "15.00" => "2000 {$text[0]} - {$text[3]}0.008/{$text[1]} - {$text[2]} {$text[3]}15.00",
        "20.00" => "3000 {$text[0]} - {$text[3]}0.007/{$text[1]} - {$text[2]} {$text[3]}20.00",
        "25.00" => "4000 {$text[0]} - {$text[3]}0.006/{$text[1]} - {$text[2]} {$text[3]}25.00",
    );

    // Select field
    woocommerce_form_field('cards_pack', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Cards Pack selection', $domain),
        'required'      => true,
        'options'       => $options,
    ),'');

    // Data to be transmitted to jQuery
    $base_price = (float) wc_get_price_to_display( $product );
    $prices = array(
        ''      => wc_price($base_price),
        '12.00' => wc_price($base_price + 12),
        '15.00' => wc_price($base_price + 15),
        '20.00' => wc_price($base_price + 20),
        '25.00' => wc_price($base_price + 25),
    )

    // jQuery code
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        var a = <?php echo json_encode($prices); ?>,
            b = 'p.price',
            c = 'select[name="cards_pack"]';

        $(c).on( 'change', function(){
            $.each( a, function( key, value ){
                if( $(c).val() == key )
                    $(b).html(value);
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}

// Add selected pack data as custom data to cart items
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_pack_data_to_cart_item_data', 20, 2 );
function add_pack_data_to_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id ){
    if( ! isset($_POST['cards_pack']) )
        return $cart_item_data;

    $pack_price = (float) sanitize_text_field( $_POST['cards_pack'] );
    if( empty($pack_price) )
        return $cart_item_data;

    if($pack_price == 12.00) $cards = 1000;
    elseif($pack_price == 15.00) $cards = 2000;
    elseif($pack_price == 20.00) $cards = 3000;
    elseif($pack_price == 25.00) $cards = 4000;

    $product    = wc_get_product($product_id); // The WC_Product Object
    $base_price = (float) $product->get_price();

    // New price calculation
    $new_price = $base_price + $pack_price;

    // Prepare and save the data array
    $cart_item_data['pack_data'] = array(
        'cards'     => (int)   $cards,
        'pack'      => (int)   $pack_price,
        'new_price' => (float) $new_price,
    );
    $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime() . rand() ); // Make each item unique

    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Set conditionally a custom item price
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_cutom_cart_item_price', 20, 1);
function set_cutom_cart_item_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    foreach (  $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( isset( $cart_item['pack_data']['new_price'] ) )
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $cart_item['pack_data']['new_price'] );
    }
}


// Display custom data in  checkout page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );
function display_custom_cart_item_data( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {
    $domain        = 'woocommerce';

    if ( isset( $cart_item['pack_data']['new_price'] ) ){
        $cart_data[] = array('name' => __( 'Cards pack', $domain ),
            'value' => $cart_item['pack_data']['cards'] );
    }
    return $cart_data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

[image]

Comment: @Loic Thanks,
But these data doesn't show in orders back-end section, i want to see whats selected option in orders screen in the backed

Comment: @user3815413 That was not asked in this question… You should search on many other StackOverFlow threads that will show you how to display that data in orders screen on the backend … Also see in ["Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters"](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) as there is a code snippet that does that (near the end)…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Can u plz take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56125544/how-to-use-multiple-filtering-options-that-will-affect-the-price-in-woocommerce

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, hi , why on shopping card just beneath the title the price is for 2000 cards reflects correct but in a few seconds it gets back to original price?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec its woocommerce mini cart , the total amount is correct but the prices for each item in mini card in a few seconds refreshes and return to original ones

Comment: @LoicTheAztec i think the problem is with sessions

Comment: @Tod After making some tests on different WooCommerce versions, since the release 3.6 when using `set_price()` method using the hook `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` the new price is not reflected in minicart only… I cart and checkout sections everything is fine. I haven't any solution for now.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec ok thanks, hope some one will come up with solution