# woocommerce_after_calculate_totals not working to update cart item price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

what I am trying to achive is if user adds a particual product in cart its price should change to zero

Here is the simple code snippet which I am using to update cart item price but

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals','set_bonus_product_pice');
function set_bonus_product_pice($cart_object){
     if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
            return;

       $free_product_ID = 10;
       foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key=>$cart_item) { 
           if($cart_item['product_id'] == $free_product_ID){
                 $cart_item['data']->set_price(0);
                 break;
           }
        }
 }
```

Woocommerce version is 4.3

In above code it goes inside if condition also set price is called properly and calling set price sets new price under change key of product object, on further dubugging it works fine until wc_get_price_excluding_tax method is called in class-wc-cart.php file , some how wc_get_price_excluding_tax method removes the change from product object.

Also I tried various variations of it like instead of using
$cart_object directly I used $woocommerce->get_cart().
The same solution has worked for me previously but not sure if its due to some change in latest version of woocommerce

Comment: is your product type is simple?

Comment: yes it a simple product with virtual type, no tax classes or any other option is applied,also I already tried $value['data']->price = $custom_price; 
this used to work for woocommerce before 3.2

Comment: check my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

change $cart_item['data']->set_price(0); to $value['data']->price = $custom_price;

check below code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_bonus_product_pice', 20, 1 );
function set_bonus_product_pice( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $custom_price    = 10; // This will be your custome price  
    $free_product_ID = 10;
    
    foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if ( $item['product_id'] == $free_product_ID ) {
            $item['data']->set_price( $custom_price );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this wont work since woocoomerce 3.2 they have made product price as private property  so you cannot set it directly. 
I forgot to method in my question that I already tried this as well

Comment: check my edits and also referred this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324605/change-cart-item-prices-in-woocommerce-3