# Add custom price in cart and wishlist from product listing page WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am making a custom plugin for WooCommerce from where I am trying to add custom prices in the cart and Wishlist from the product listing page but the price is not getting through to the cart and Wishlist. Is there any other way to do it? The Product listing page has add to cart button from WooCommerce as the regular price value is set to 0.

```
    // Display custom price on the product listing page for specific categories
    add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'display_custom_price_on_product_listing', 25);

    function display_custom_price_on_product_listing()

{
    global $product, $wpdb;

    if (has_term(array('ring', 'rings', 'pendants', 'mangalsutra', 'mangalsutras', 'bracelet', 'bracelets'), 'product_cat')) {
        extract(get_all_product_data($product, true));

        // Load data from custom tables for further calculations
        $metal_purity_percent_new  = get_metal_purity($metal_purity); // Metal Purity percent
        

        $diamond_total = $dqone + $dqtwo + $dqthree + $dqfour + $dqfive + $dqsix + $dqseven + $dqeight + $dqnine + $dqten;

        // Fetch color stone price
        $colorstone_price = get_colorstone($colorstone);
        $colorstone_weightnew = (float) $product->get_attribute('colorstone-weight');
        // Calculate color stone total
        $colorstone_total = $colorstone_price * $colorstone_weightnew;
        $alltax = get_extra_charges();
        $gst = get_gst();
        // Calculations
        $gold_value_new = ($gold_rate * $metal_purity_percent_new) / 100; // Gold value
        $mc = makingcharge($net_weight, $metal_type);
        $rt = makingchargerate_type($net_weight, $metal_type);
        if ($rt == 'Flat') {
            if ($net_weight < 2) {
                $flatrate = $mc;
            } else {
                $flatrate = $mc * $net_weight;
            }
        } else {
            $gold_valuerate = ($gold_rate * $metal_purity_percent_new) / 100;
            $percentagerate = ($gold_valuerate * $mc) / 100;
            $flatrate = $percentagerate * $net_weight;
        }

        $totalvalue = round(($gold_value_new * $net_weight) + $regular_price + $colorstone_total + $alltax +  $diamond_total + $flatrate); // Custom price calculation with two decimal places

        $custom_price = $totalvalue + (($totalvalue * $gst) / 100);


        // Displaying custom price
        echo '<p class="product-custom-price" style="font-size: 20px;" >' . wc_price($custom_price) . '</p>';

        echo '<input type="hidden" id="listing_price" name="listing_price" value="' . $custom_price . '">';
    }
?>


<?php
}
```

I tried

```
// Add custom cart item data
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_custom_cart_item_data', 10, 2);
function save_custom_cart_item_data($cart_item_data, $product_id)
{

    if (isset($_POST['listing_price']) && !empty($_POST['listing_price'])) {
        $cart_item_data['listing_price'] = (float) esc_html($_POST['listing_price']); // Custom calculated price
    }

    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Comment: To change cart item prices in WooCommerce version 3.0+ you need to: 1) use `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` hook. 2) To use `WC_Cart get_cart()` method. 3)
use `WC_product set_price()` method. Please see: [Change cart item prices in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43327167/10497022)

Comment: Hey @Richard, this solution is not working for me as the price is getting calculated dynamically.